# Make every numeric value in a pandas DataFrame negative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I make every `pandas` DataFrame value negative? I couldn't find this answer listed and thought it may provide a good reference for anyone learning how to work with data in the `pandas` DataFrame.

```
In [1]: frame
Out[1]:
       position
index
0          6
1          7
2          7
3          7
4          8
5          9
6          1
7          1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do `- frame` (or `*-1`):

```
In [122]: -frame
Out[122]:
       position
index
0            -6
1            -7
2            -7
3            -7
4            -8
5            -9
6            -1
7            -1
```

As noted by others, this will not work if you also have non-numeric columns. A way to select all numeric columns:

```
frame.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
```

And if already negative values should stay negative, indeed use `abs()` as noted by @Easypeasy. Then this becomes:

```
- frame.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).abs()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can apply any operator or across a column. To mutate it in-place, just multiply the column by -1:

```
>>> frame = pd.DataFrame({'position': [6,7,7,7,8,9,1,1]})
>>> frame['position'] *= -1
>>> frame
   position
0        -6
1        -7
2        -7
3        -7
4        -8
5        -9
6        -1
7        -1
```

But in this case, you don't even need to specify a column, because it's the only one you have, so just:

```
>>> frame *= -1
```

If you want to create a copy instead of mutating in-place, that's even simple:

```
>>> frame * -1
```

… or, equivalently and even more simply:

```
>>> -frame
```

Comment: Is there a way to test a condition on this? For instance, it the value of a different column equals "credit" I want to keep it positive, but if it's "debit" I want it to be negative

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will do what you want. However, if you already have some negative numbers in your DataFrame, but want all to be, then this will do:

`frame.apply(lambda x: -x.abs(), axis=1)`

Comment: You don't need the apply, just do `-frame.abs()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) like so:

```
In [1]: f = lambda x: -x; frame.apply(f, axis=1)
Out[1]:
       position
index
0         -6
1         -7
2         -7
3         -7
4         -8
5         -9
6         -1
7         -1
```